# "Undefined variable print" error in python program

Tags: python, aptana

I created a very simple program in python with a main method that prints out `Hello`. Aptana studio is giving me an error that says

`Undefined variable: Print`

I am using `python 3.4` and `aptana 3`

Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it?

```
def main():
    print("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is this the exact code you have? Because `Print` and `print` are not the same thing.

Comment: Also are you using `print` as a variable name anywhere? Because you shouldn't.

Comment: I don't think python3.4 works in aptana 3.